# Event onclick + clickable link (like facebook photo "theater")

Tags: jquery

I use the same technique used by facebook javascript to display photographs.

If a user clicks on a picture (in facebook stream), the href is blocked, and part of an "onclick" event that shows the photos in "Theater. "

You can still click the right mouse button on picture and select "Open in new tab" and the picture is open in normal mode.

If I use

```
$("a").removeAttr ("href").css("cursor", "pointer");
```

within the event "onclick", the user can not click with the right sull'link and open the page in a new tab.

What to do? Ideas?

---

User click on a href link
Example

function Message()
{
$("a").removeAttr ("href").css("cursor", "pointer");
//do something...
}

using this trick User cannot click with right button of mouse and choose "open in a new tab"

Comment: im not sure what u want to do

Comment: User click on a href link
<a href="page.php" onclick="javascript:Message()">Example</a>

function Message()
{
$("a").removeAttr ("href").css("cursor", "pointer");
//do something...
}

using this trick User cannot click with right button of mouse and choose "open in a new tab"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to stop the url from opening on click, but still be able to right-click to open?  Easy, friend, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PbKZu/1/) for the code.

Trust me, you don't want to use `onclick=''`, nor do you want to bind this way: `$("#links a").click(function(e){});` You only want to bind to one element because the more binds you have, the more resources your computer needs to run, typically slowing your code down.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put '#' in href, or you can add function on click which return false:

$('a').click(function(){return false;});

cheers

Comment: Don't put # in the href: in some browsers it will jump their viewport up to the top of the page.